# Python String Split

Tags: python

New to python.

I am trying to parse the output of "fdisk -l"

```
    Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848 254308949 254102102 121.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       254310398 488396799 234086402 111.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       254310400 478828543 224518144 107.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       478830592 488396799   9566208   4.6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

I have this code:

```
import os

for line in os.popen('/sbin/fdisk -l').readlines():
    if line.find('/dev/') !=0: continue
    columns = line.split()
    print columns[0].split('/')[-1]

    print columns[1]
```

Which produces this output:

```
sda1
*
sda2
206848
sda3
254310398
sda5
254310400
sda6
478830592
```

Aside from the obvious formatting issues which i will sort later, how can i stop it from recognising the Asterisk on the Boot column?

I know i could probably solve this issue with something like AWK to completely ignore the Boot column, but id like to try to do this with Python as im still learning.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the answer using "re.split"

```
for line in os.popen('/sbin/fdisk -l').readlines():
if line.find('/dev/') !=0: continue
columns = re.split("[, \-!?:\*]+", line)
print columns[0]
print columns[1]
```

Gives:

```
    /dev/sda1
2048
/dev/sda2
206848
/dev/sda3
254310398
/dev/sda5
254310400
/dev/sda6
478830592
```